# Creating multiple text nodes in HTML

Tags: html

If I have the HTML

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>"Foo" "Bar"</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

is there any way to hav the browser emit `"Foo"` and `"Bar"` as two text nodes so it rendered the same as `<div>FooBar</div>`? I know that, with JavaScript, you can add two text nodes as children of a div to achieve this result, but I'm wondering if it's possible in vanilla HTML. The reason I ask is because I'm workin on an SSR engine that does partial hydration, and the JS engine is looking for several text nodes in an HTML element but I can only manage to create one. Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: No, the HTML parser will always create a single text node.

Comment: I believe you can. You will need to put a non-text-node between the two. This could be the [`<wbr>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr). You might also simply wrap the words in their own `<span>`s.

Comment: Also a Comment is a non-text node `Foo <!-- --> Bar`.